# Can't run Olarila Ventura on VirtualBox

Tags: macos, mac, virtualbox, ventura

I'm trying to run Olarila Ventura on VirtualBox but I get stuck on this.

[image]

I have done these commands on cmd as an admin

```
CD "C:\Program Files\Oracle\Virtualbox"

VBoxManage.exe modifyvm "mac" --cpuidset 00000001 000106e5 00100800 0098e3fd bfebfbff

VBoxManage setextradata "mac" "VBoxInternal/Devices/efi/0/Config/DmiSystemProduct" "iMac11,3"

VBoxManage setextradata "mac" "VBoxInternal/Devices/efi/0/Config/DmiSystemVersion" "1.0"

VBoxManage setextradata "mac" "VBoxInternal/Devices/efi/0/Config/DmiBoardProduct" "Iloveapple"

VBoxManage setextradata "mac" "VBoxInternal/Devices/smc/0/Config/DeviceKey" "ourhardworkbythesewordsguardedpleasedontsteal(c)AppleComputerInc"
```

So can anyone help?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not appear to be about Apple hardware or software within the scope defined in the [help center](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), specifically *Installing or using Apple operating systems on non-Apple hardware (and most other explicitly unlicensed use of product)*